# removeView causing multiple EditTexts to have focus

Tags: java, android

I wrote a class to dynamically display EditTexts as you need them. So in any case where an interface needs a variable amount of inputs for strings the class generates the needed EditTexts. It does this by supplying an extra blank EditText at all times. It also removes those that are not used. Any editText that loses focus that is blank is destroyed unless it is the last remaining EditText.

It works pretty well except for the fact that leaving a blank EditText and making it lose focus removes it but also sets the focus to the first EditText on the page (which isn't dynamic it's part of the page's XML) as well as whatever other field I clicked on. So I have two cursors and can no longer edit the first field on the page.

I think what's happening is when the EditText loses focus and is destroyed android is setting focus to the default field on the page and then when the next field gains focus that gets a cursor too. It's something to do with the removal of the EditText I believe.

I really like this functionality though so I would like to get it working. Here is the code for my class:

```
package com.bentles.attempt3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SmartEditTexts {
    List<EditText> boxes = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    Context context;
    ViewGroup parent;
    int index;

public SmartEditTexts(Context context, ViewGroup parent, int index)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.index = index + 1;
    add();
}

private void add()
{
    EditText newEdit = new EditText(context);

    newEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            EditText changed= (EditText)v;

            if (hasFocus)
            {
                if (boxes.indexOf(changed) == (boxes.size() - 1)) 
                {
                    add();
                }                   
            }
            else if (changed.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) //if there's nothing in the box
            {
                remove(changed); //try to get rid of the box
            }

        }
    }); 

    boxes.add(newEdit);
    parent.addView(newEdit, index + boxes.indexOf(newEdit));        
}

private void remove(EditText remover)
{
    if (boxes.size() > 1)
    {
        boxes.remove(remover);
        parent.removeView(remover);         
    }
}

public List<String> toStrings()
{
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(EditText a: boxes)
    {
        if (!a.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty())
        strings.add(a.getText().toString().trim());         
    }

    return strings;
}
}
```

Comment: i think you can use setrequestfocus false on remove

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.
I can call
    remover.requestFocus()
or
    remover.isFocusable(false)

but neither seems to do anything. Is there another method I should call? And where should I call it?